# CsvParser - everything loads into one column only

Tags: java, csv

what might be the reason for such a behaviour?

I've got a csv file that looks more or less like this:

```
Name Verkaufsartikel;Name Sorte;Name Halbfertigware;Name Tierart;Werk;Werk Bezeichnung;Materialnummer;Materialkurztext;Materialnummer (HFW);Materialkurztext (HFW);Warengruppe;Warengruppe Bezeichnung;Länderkürzel;Gebindegröße/Nettogewicht;Gewichtseinheit;Produkthierarchie Ebene 1 Schlüssel;Produkthierarchie Ebene 1 Text;Produkthierarchie Ebene 2 Schlüssel;Produkthierarchie Ebene 2 Text;Produkthierarchie Ebene 3 Schlüssel;Produkthierarchie Ebene 3 Text;Branding Schlüssel;Branding Bezeichnung;EAN Nummer;Linie/Welt;Linie Code;Höhe Palette;Alte Materialnummer (navision);Qualitätsstandard;Qualitätsstandard Bezeichnung;Exklusivprodukt;Länderfreigabe für Artikel (Verkaufsländer des Artikels);Basispreis (PR00 Verkaufspreis);VTL-überg. Status;Werksüb. MatStatus;FLAG B2B;Probenpaket;Mindestbestellmenge;Maximalbestellmenge;Liefereinheit;Zolltarifnummer;Verpackungsart;Verpackungseinheit;Höhe Produkt;Breite Produkt;Tiefe Produkt;Höhe Verpackungseinheit;Breite Verpackungseinheit;Tiefe Verpackungseinheit;EAN Nummer Verpackungseinheit;Bruttogewicht;Palettentyp;Mindest MHD;Herkunftsland;Anzahl Verpackungseinheiten pro Palette;Anzahl Verpackungseinheiten pro Lage;Basismengeneinheit
VP Karton 385x285x330mm companyName;n/a;;Verpackung;1000;companyName;20000001;VP Karton 385x285x330mm companyName;;;221;VP-S-Kartonage;DE;0.600;KG;CO005;CO: other;CO00500014;Verpackung;CO0050001499999999;n/a;999;N/A;;N/A;999;2.130.000;1001965;999;N/A;Nein;;;;;;;         0.000;         0.000;           0.000;48191000;;;2.130.000;         0.000;         0.000;         0.000;         0.000;         0.000;;         0.630;JEU2;0;DE;360;2;ST
```

and I'm using a CsvParser to parse it, I tried both entering the header array:

```
records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader( headerArray).parse( in);
```

as letting it discover the header by itself:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( new File( sourceCSVPath));
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new BOMInputStream( fis), "UTF-8");
final CSVParser recsFromParser = new CSVParser( reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader());
```

unfortunately whatever I do, the records I iterate over contain ONLY ONE column with all the record contents. The record contents is not being split with semicolons. what might be the reason?

Comment: try setting delimeter explicitly for CSVParser as semi-colon or enable auto-detection using CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();    settings.setDelimiterDetectionEnabled(true); CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);    ........... may be its looking for comma as default delimeter

Comment: not available in org.apache.commons.csv...

Comment: try CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.newFormat(';'); final CSVParser recsFromParser = new CSVParser( reader, csvFormat);

Comment: or better just use final CSVParser recsFromParser = new CSVParser( reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withDelimiter(';');